# How to find terraria player files on rooted android

Tags: android, terraria-mobile

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab A6 10.1 2016 (model SM-T580) with Android version 7.0.

I wanted to find the player and world files, and I found out I needed to root my device. So I rooted it, (it really is rooted, I used a PC) and I went to /Android/data/com.505games.TerrariaPaid/, and I didn't see a files folder. I saw this: [image: no files folder here] I also tried a root file browser and I the same thing happened. Please help me find my files folder with the player and world files in it. Thanks.

Comment: This does not seem like a root folder in the screenshot; I think you're in the phone's internal storage (a part of it's own storage that's being treated like an sdcard on modern Android). Try checking in the real root - /. There should be no Android folder, and the data should instead be in /data/data where app install data from the APKs is stored.